# CSS div height auto not working with AJAX

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I'm working on a project where a javascript function creates a modal and uses HTML from an external page to fill the modal. However, I am running into a problem. Using CSS, I have my modal's window set to "auto" height, which works just fine when it stands alone without being requested by AJAX. See working example here: https://codepen.io/dansbyt/pen/VwbYdMJ

However, the tricky part comes whenever I call on the modal using AJAX. The height does not set properly at all. [This is a reference photo of what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3IwR.png). In this reference photo, it seems as though the height of the `.modal-window` is about 160px, which I assume comes from `grid-template-rows: 90px 1fr 60px;` (each of these numbers added together)

I do not understand what I am doing wrong, because everything seems to be working whenever I take AJAX out of the equation, as shown in the Codepen example. What is going on?

**Main Page:**

```
<html>

  <h1> Testing Modal </h1>
  <a onclick='taskInfo("1")'>Launch Modal</a>

  <div id="infoModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-window">
      <span id="moreInfo"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

</html>


<script>                                                                        /* AJAX name selector */
  var infoModal = document.getElementById("infoModal");

  function assInfo(str){
     infoModal.style.display = "block";
     fetch("moreinfo.tem.php?assID=" + str).then((response) =>response.text()).then((text) => {
          var parser = new DOMParser();
          var doc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html");
          var ele = doc.documentElement;
          var scripts = ele.getElementsByTagName('script');
          for(var script of scripts){
              var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
              var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
              scriptElement.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
              scriptElement.innerText = script.innerText;
              head.appendChild(scriptElement);
              head.removeChild(scriptElement);
         }
         document.getElementById("moreInfo").innerHTML=text;
        });
  }

  function taskInfo(str){
     infoModal.style.display = "block";
     fetch("moreinfo.tem.php?taskID=" + str).then((response) =>response.text()).then((text) => {
          var parser = new DOMParser();
          var doc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html");
          var ele = doc.documentElement;
          var scripts = ele.getElementsByTagName('script');
          for(var script of scripts){
              var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
              var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
              scriptElement.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
              scriptElement.innerText = script.innerText;
              head.appendChild(scriptElement);
              head.removeChild(scriptElement);
         }
         document.getElementById("moreInfo").innerHTML=text;
        });
  }

  window.onclick = function(event) {                                              /* Make modal disappear when you click "X" */
    if (event.target == infoModal) {infoModal.style.display = "none";}
  }
</script>
```

**External Page (moreinfo.tem.php)**

```
<div class='modal-top'>
      <img class='big pic' src='../../resources/pics/teachers/1.jpg'>
      <span class='title'>Genre Worksheet</span>
      <span class='due'>Due 1w ago</span>
    </div>
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <div class='directions'>
        <b>Directions: </b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu.
      </div>
      <textarea placeholder='Type Question..'></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class='modal-controls'>
      <button id='askforhelp' class='button green-btn' onclick='askHelp("showform")'>Ask for Help</button>
      <button id='markdone' class='button green-btn'>Mark as Done</button>
      <button id='sendmsg' class='button green-btn'>Send Message</button>
      <button id='cancelmsg' class='button grey-btn' onclick='askHelp("hideform")'>Cancel Message</button>
    </div>
<script>

  function askHelp(arg) {

    var window = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-window')[0];
    var textbox = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];

    var helpBtn = document.getElementById('askforhelp');
    var doneBtn = document.getElementById('markdone');
    var sendBtn = document.getElementById('sendmsg');
    var cancelBtn = document.getElementById('cancelmsg');

    if (arg == "showform") {
      window.style.height = 'calc(auto + 100px)';
      textbox.style.display = 'block';
      helpBtn.style.display = 'none';
      doneBtn.style.display = 'none';
      sendBtn.style.display = 'block';
      cancelBtn.style.display = 'block';
    }

    if (arg == "hideform") {
      window.style.height = 'auto';
      textbox.style.display = 'none';
      helpBtn.style.display = 'block';
      doneBtn.style.display = 'block';
      sendBtn.style.display = 'none';
      cancelBtn.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

</script>

<style>
 .modal {
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 20;
   right: 0; top: 0;
   width: 100%; height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
   animation-name: fadeIn;
   animation-duration: 0.4s}

 .modal-window{
   display: grid;
   position: fixed;
   padding: 10px;
   width: 600px; height: auto;
   top: 50%; left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   border-radius: 16px;
   background-color: white;
   transition: height 0.5s;
   grid-template-rows: 90px 1fr 60px;
   grid-template-areas:
     "top"
     "content"
     "controls";}

 /* --------[TOP] -------- */
 .modal-top {
   display: grid;
   grid-area: top;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #5B7042;
   grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr 120px;}

 .big.pic{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 65px;
   clip-path: circle();
   margin-left: 10px;}

 .modal-top .title {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   font-weight: 800;
   font-size: 26px}

 .due {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   font-size: 18px;
   color: gray;}


 /* --------[CONTENT] -------- */
 .modal-content {
   display: block;
   grid-area: content;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   padding: 12px;}

 .directions {
   font-size: 18px;
   line-height: 1.7}

 textarea {
   display: none;
   width: 100%; height: 100px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-size: 18px !important;
   margin-top: 20px;}

 /* --------[CONTROLS] -------- */
 .modal-controls {
   grid-area: controls;
   display: flex;
  justify-content: center;}

 #askforhelp {margin-right: 10px;}

 #sendmsg {display: none; margin-right: 10px}
 #cancelmsg {display: none}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has nothing to do with AJAX. `.modal-window` is set to `display: grid;` with `grid-template-rows: 90px 1fr 60px;`, but remember the response of your AJAX request goes inside `#moreInfo` as we see here `document.getElementById("moreInfo").innerHTML=text;`.

What this means is that, `.modal-window` has only one child, `#moreInfo`, which forms one row with a maximum height of 90px.

To fix this leave `.modal-window` as `display: block;` and copy the grid styles to `#moreInfo`.

Comment: I had a fundamental lack of understanding with what was happening with the AJAX request, so I appreciate your solution and explanation. Thank you!!